# Can Eclipse Vert.x support phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, vert.x

I've been evaluating whether vertx can replace my current Apache+Tomcat. One thing I don't yet understand if there is a way to support the phpmyadmin tool or if there is an alternative?

Comment: Running any non-JVM code, like PHP, on the JVM might be difficult to achieve. If you only want to configure things, you are far better off with the standard setup, which is Apache or nginx or even IIS.